# Edittext returns empty String

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

I am posting a dialog window via handler to the UI and want to retrieve String from the EditText when I hit OK, but it always returns empty String.
My code:

```
    public void showLabelDialog() {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder((Activity) getThis());
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getThis()).getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.label_dialog, null);
            final EditText edt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.label_dialog);
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    setCurrentLabel(edt.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println("Current text:" + edt.getText().toString());
                    labeled = true;
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    setCurrentLabel(null);
                    labeled = true;
                }
            });
            AlertDialog b = builder.create();
            b.show();
        }
    });
}
```

The output is:

I/System.out: Current text:

The label_dialog.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/label_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="@string/label_dialog"
    android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u post label_dialog.xml?

Comment: try using final `EditText edt=(EditText)dialogview. findViewById(R.id.label_dialog);`

Comment: The issue is solved, but I will post the label_dialog.xml in case it helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please call your `EditText` from your dialog view, you are referencing edittext in activity now, but you need to call it from your dialog view

`final EditText edt = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_dialog);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 public void showLabelDialog() {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (MainActivity.this).getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.label_dialog, null);
            final EditText edt=(EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_dialog);
            builder.setView(dialogView);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //setCurrentLabel(edt.getText().toString());
                    System.out.println("Current text:" + edt.getText().toString());
                    //labeled = true;
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //setCurrentLabel(null);
                    //labeled = true;
                }
            });
            AlertDialog b = builder.create();
            b.show();
        }
```

that is use,

```
final EditText edt=(EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_dialog);
```

instead of

```
final EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.label_dialog);
```

Happy coding.!!!